# index 49793 out of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a strange problem, i can't even get the source of it.

I'm using ajax GET request to a specified url, that routes to `:controller => pages`, `:action => make_affiche_link`, there i have the following:

```
@album = Album.find( params[:album_id] )
@upd = { :affiche_id => params[:affiche_id] }

if @album.update_attributes( @upd )
  @out = {:key => '1', :message => "success"}
  render :json, @out.to_json
else
  @out = {:key => '0', :message => "something bad is going here..."}
  render :json => @out.to_json
end
```

and what i get is this:

```
index 49793 out of string
```

And i have both `:affiche_id` and `:album_id` in params properly

Thank you for any help!

Comment: after i'm done with that problem, i'll change GET request to POST, of course

Comment: stack backtrace would be helpful

Comment: `index 49793 out of string` can't be the whole error description there must be more info

Comment: @M2_ Look in `RAILS_ROOT/log/development.log` or whatever your environment name is. Post the relevant bits of info from there to here so that we can help you figure this out.

Comment: damn, it was silly. I looked up the log file, and it pointed on a string with a misspelling, as you can see above `render :json, @out...` there must be `=>` instead of comma. And the worth that several minutes ago i corrected this mistake just near =\ Thank you!

Comment: Just got here from Google.  Good thing about Stackoverflow is no mapper how silly you're being, someone else has already done it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It is Json  @out = {:key => '1', :message => "success"}, you try convert Json to Json @out.to_json. Use  render :json, @out